# How can I get apache to list a folders contents?

Tags: apache, directory

How can I get Apache to display the contents of my folder and provide links to them? Similar to http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/?

I don't have access to the Apache configuration, so I'm looking for something in the way of .htaccess or something I can do in just my home folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the option Indexes in the Apache configuration.

For instance, in the .htaccess file for your directory (if you can use those, and have sufficient privileges), you could put :

```
Options +Indexes
```

This functionality is provided by [`mod_autoindex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html), which has lots of options to allow fine-tuning of the generated output, btw

To get this working, that module must be loaded, and to be able to activate the option in an .htaccess file, you will need the admin of the server to give you some privileges *(with the `AllowOverride` directive in the Apache's main config file, if I remember correctly -- well, your admin should know that better than me anyway ^^ )*